# Remove duplicated in the sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below sql query. i am using oracle 10g. here i am combining results from both the queries.

```
select distinct combined.some_id from (
  SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
        union all  
        SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica e where
        e.some_code  ='ABC' and e.code_two IN('S','H') and e.some_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H'))
    ) combined,tableA_Replica_join_table_ONE x where 
        combined.some_id = x.some_id(+)
        AND (x.status   IN('ACTIVE','INACTIVE'))


        UNION

select distinct combined.some_id from (
  SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
        union all  
        SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica e where
        e.some_code  ='ABC' and e.code_two IN('S','H') and e.some_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H'))
    ) combined,tableA_Replica_join_table_TWO x where 
        combined.some_id = x.some_id(+)
        AND (x.status   IN('ACTIVE','INACTIVE'))
```

in both the queries below part is common.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
        union all  
        SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica e where
        e.some_code  ='ABC' and e.code_two IN('S','H') and e.some_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H'))
```

how can i avoid code duplication in both the queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE, also sometimes called "WITH statement"):

```
WITH combined AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
        union all  
        SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica e where
        e.some_code  ='ABC' and e.code_two IN('S','H') and e.some_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H'))
)
SELECT distinct combined.some_id
FROM combined, tableA_Replica_join_table_ONE x
WHERE combined.some_id = x.some_id(+)
      AND (x.status   IN('ACTIVE','INACTIVE'))

UNION

SELECT distinct combined.some_id
FROM combined, tableA_Replica_join_table_TWO x
WHERE combined.some_id = x.some_id(+)
      AND (x.status   IN('ACTIVE','INACTIVE'))
```

Comment: Thanks much for ur response. query is working now. in with clause am doing union of two queries here how can i add order by some_id ? Please help me....

Comment: @user1016403: If you want to sort the result of a UNION, you can do `SELECT * FROM (... UNION ...) ORDER BY col`

Answer (score 1):

This query removes a lot of the duplication:

```
select distinct combined.some_id from (
        SELECT distinct l.some_id FROM tableA
           union
        SELECT distinct e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica
    ) combined
    inner join (
        select x.status, x.some_id from tableA_Replica_join_table_ONE x 
             union
        select y.status, y.some_id from tableA_Replica_join_table_TWO y 
    ) join_table
    on combined.some_id = join_table.some_id(+) and
       join_table.status IN('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') and
       combined.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
```

What query is the best depends on the structure of your data, always.

One thing that you definitely don't need to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H')
        union all  
        SELECT DISTINCT e.some_id FROM tableA_Replica e where
        e.some_code  ='ABC' and e.code_two IN('S','H') and e.some_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT l.some_id FROM tableA l where
        l.some_code  ='ABC' and l.code_two IN('S','H'))
```

You do not need that `NOT IN` clause in the second query.  Just use `union` instead of `union all`--it removes the duplicates automatically.

Another thing to think about: you are using `distinct` in a large number of places.  Do you really need all of those?  Some people seem to use `distinct` everywhere as a way to guard against duplicates.  However, this is inefficient and can lead to subtle errors if you don't know exactly what it is doing.

As a rule, only use `distinct` when you have specifically decided that you needed to remove duplicates from a particular query. (It is impossible to know whether or not you need all of them without seeing your data, but the large number of them makes me suspicious).